# Настройка location в nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

Создал папку `/data/www` как сказано в инструкции на офф. сайте. В нее положил файл `index.html`. Далее открыл конфигурационный файл и в конец блока http(который там уже был) добавил следующее:

```
server {
    location / {
        root /data/www/;
    }
    location /images/ {
        root /data/;
    }
}
```

Далее перезагужаю nginx-демона так: `sudo nginx -s reload`.

После всего этого захожу на http://localhost/index.html. В ответ вижу 404. **Что я делаю не так ?**

Система ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: По стандартам дебиан/убунту конфигурация своего сервера должна быть в папке sites-available и линкой в sites-enabled. И надо бы убрать default оттуда

Comment: Спасибо. А можно чуть поподробней ?

Comment: В подкаталоге /etc/nginx/sites-available складываются все-все конфиги, даже те, которые вы раньше использовали, а теперь не используете. В sites-enabled (в основном конфиге есть include конфигом из этой директории) складываются используемые конфиги, принято делать их симлинками на конфиги в sites-available.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Полагаю, вы не описали в должной степени конфигурацию сервера для nginx. Не указали домен (server_name) и порт (listen).
Минимальный конфиг server'a должен выглядеть примерно вот так:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;
    access_log   logs/localhost.access.log;
    root /data/www/;

    location /images/ {
        root /data/;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ошибка: `nginx: [emerg] unknown log format "main" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:66`

Comment: попробуйте исправить эту строку на 
access_log   logs/localhost.access.log; 
или вообще закомментируйте ее с помощью # в начале строки. Главное сейчас не логи, с ними и потом разберемся.

Comment: Закоментировал. Результат такой же - 404.

Comment: nginx restart делали? reload, если не ошибаюсь, недостаточен для таких серьезных изменений в конфиге, как добавление server. Если рестартили и все так же не работает - покажите полный конфиг, пожалуйста.

Comment: А как делать `nginx restart` ? Если в консоль так и написать, то в ответ получаю сообщение о том, что команда `restart` не была найдена. Вот ссылка на полный кониг: https://github.com/Faoxis/nginx/blob/master/nginx.conf

Comment: sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart

Comment: Сделал рестарт - не помогло.

Comment: Проверил конфиг у себя на сервере. Он почти рабочий. При первой попытке запуска вывалилась ошибка Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] "worker_processes" directive invalid number in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
Я заменил "auto" на "4", рестарт прошел нормально. Индексный файл открылся. Из вероятных проблем еще вижу занятый порт 80: у вас не запущен apache, к примеру, который занимает 80 порт? Или может скайп (да, и такое бывает)?

Comment: Нашел в чем дело. В мой конфиг по умолчанию был подключен файл  /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default, который перебивал мой конфиг. После того как я его удалил все заработало. Спасибо за помощь. )